# Import JQuery-Library causes continious refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, refresh

I've come an issue that i can't explain

consider the follwing head of a html page

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
<meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1">
<meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
<meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ControleInput() {

        document.getElementById('Ophalen_button').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('Wegschrijven_button').disabled = true;
        var allFields = true;

        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een FS-Nummer
        if (document.getElementById('FSNummer').value.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('Ophalen_button').disabled = false;
        }
        else
        {allFields = false; }

        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een alias
        if (!document.getElementById('AliasPartner').value.length > 0)
        { allFields = false; }
        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een BTW-Nummer
        if (!document.getElementById('BtwNummerLeverancier').value.length > 0)
        { allFields = false; }
        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een afkorting
        if (!document.getElementById('Afkorting').value.length > 0)
        { allFields = false; }

        if (allFields) {
            document.getElementById('<%=Wegschrijven_button.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function ConfirmIgnoreBTWNbr() {
        if (confirm("Dit BTW-Nummer is reeds in gebruik. Deze zal bij het wegschrijven van gegevens worden overgeslagen. Is dit in orde?")) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "SalesSetupHIC.aspx?action=sendData"
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Code on the page_behind (loaded event)

```
    Fouttekst.Text = String.Empty
    //enable disable some buttons and do some layoutactions

    Dim WindowsUser As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
    t.Toegelaten(WindowsUser)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

         //Perform some layoutactions

    End If

    //Get Some Data
    If (ListBoxBtwNummers.Items.Count = 0) Then
        ListBoxBtwNummers.DataSource = _myProxy.GetBTWNummersInGebruik(WindowsUser)
        ListBoxBtwNummers.DataBind()
    End If

    //Add some handlers
    FSNummer.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")
    AliasPartner.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")
    BtwNummerLeverancier.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")
    Afkorting.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")

    //If Querystring is present do something
    If (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) Then
        WegschrijvenData()
    End If
```

Now this page performs a constant refreshing of the page when I visit it using:

```
 http://**MyPcName**/VirtualDirectory>/Default.aspx.
 http://**MyIP-Adres**/VirtualDirectory>/Default.aspx
```

But not when I visit the page like

```
 http://**localhost**/VirtualDirectory>/Default.aspx
 http://**127.0.0.1**/VirtualDirectory>/Default.aspx
```

The problem lies with

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

removing the library resolves the refreshing issue. But prevents me from using the ajax-function. I've tried many ways to include the library, but so far without luck.

So my questions regarding this incident are

***1) Why does the constant refresh happen?***

***2) How do i work around it?(while still using JQuery ofc)***

***3) What debugger to use in situations like this (Firebug/IE-Console) aren't helping***

Any new ideas are welcome aswell.

Thanks

**Update**: referring to another lib of jquery (locally and on the internet) didn't resolve the issue either. Other applications continue to use this same lib without issues.

**Update**: Debugging using Firebug/IE-Console didn't result in any solutions. I'm still stuck.

Comment: Have you tried loading JQuery from somewhere else like the Google Hosted Library to see if there is just a problem with the library you're accessing?

Comment: can you try by copying your JQuery in your local application and giving reference of it ?

Comment: Attempted both solutions without luck. Google Hosted Library was my original source. thats why i hope it would be solved when changing to Code.query.com . Maintaining a copy local of Jquery still produced the same bloody result :-| . Jquery just doesn't like me anymore i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some painfull searching we finally came across the origin of the problem. The problem did not had anything to do anything with `Jquery` or the used methods.

The original developer created the solution using VS2008. Yet he did not 'clean up' his html. As a result of relying on VS 2008, the following code appread in the html

```
<body id="PageBody" runat="server" bgcolor="#b0c4de" ms_positioning="GridLayout"
onresize="document.location=window.location;">
```

Obviously the error lies here: `onresize="document.location=window.location;"`
Removing this line dit solve the constant flickering of the webpage.  Most likely Jquery has trigger somewhere that is being fired when the page is resized.

Conclusion of this affair:

1. Never rely on HTML generated from VS (this i knew)
2. Never rely on HTML written by your predecessors

Thanks to everyone who made the effort solving my problem!